# Rails 5 collection_select: Showing multiple attributes in one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, collection-select

I'm trying to make a collection select which shows two attributes from two different models.

I want to select an account. The account has a name and an owner. The owner is a model which also has the attribute name.
When using the collection select I want it to show: `account.name + owner.name`. This is currently the collection_select I have which only shows the `account.name`

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :to_account_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :to_account_id, Account.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
```

ex: A account has name **Main account** and the owner of the account is **Stan**, when selecting it should show **Stan - Main account**.

worked with:

```
    <%= f.collection_select :to_account_id, Account.all.map{|a| ["#{a.owner.name} - #{a.name}", a.id] },:second,:first %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code

```
 <%= f.collection_select :to_account_id, Account.all.map{|a| ["#{a.name} - #{a.owner.name}", a.id] } %>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Just had to edit the code abit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Classification < ApplicationRecord

  def class_detail
    "#{definition} #{description}"
  end
end
```

```
<%= form.collection_select(:classification_id, Classification.order(:classification), :id, :class_detail, prompt: true)%>
```